# choose columns in unknown type serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm using something like:

```
var users = somelinqquery;
```

Currently, I'm returning a serialized users using:

```
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
     new { Result = true, Users = users }
    );
```

The User object have more properties that I need to serialize, age, birthday, etc...

How can I choose what properties to serialize, something like:

```
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
     new { Result = true, Users = new { Id = users.id, Name = users.name } }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ScriptIgnore` attribute to your field/property

```
public class User
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string IgnoreThisField= "aaa";
    public string Name = "Joe";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) for this specific type.

By overriding `IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object, JavaScriptSerializer)` you'll include only those values that needs to be converted.

`IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes` will ensure that only the types that you specify will be passed into this method.

**Edit**

I'm adding a code snippet to illustrate my point.

```
public class Foo {
    public String FooField { get; set; }
    public String NotSerializedFooString { get; set; }
}
public class FooConverter : JavaScriptConverter {
    public override Object Deserialize(IDictionary<String, Object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IDictionary<String, Object> Serialize(Object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) {
        // Here I'll get instances of Foo only.
        var data = obj as Foo;

        // Prepare a dictionary
        var dic = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

        // Include only those values that should be there
        dic["FooField"] = data.FooField;

        // return the dictionary
        return dic;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes {
        get {
            // I return the array with only one element.
            // This means that this converter will be used with instances of
            // only this type.
            return new[] { typeof(Foo) };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curiosity. how can you differentiate the fields by `Type`s, can `SupportedTypes` give you the field name to exclude from serialization if many fields have the same type like "string"?